# Windows service written in Python works only in debug mode

Tags: python, websocket, windows-services

I've written a simple Windows service which should use websockets to report status of VirtualBox machines.

After installing and starting the service, my websocket server receives a connection request but the connection gets closed almost instantly.

server output when I start the service

```
running on port 8888
new connection
connection closed
```

Running the service with `pythonservice.exe -debug myservice` opens a websocket connection and sends the data I expect.

Server output when I start the service **with debug flag**

```
running on port 8888
new connection
message received VM NAME: win1, Memory: 111, CPUS: 1
message received VM NAME: win2, Memory: 266, CPUS: 1
message received VM NAME: win3, Memory: 256, CPUS: 1
message received VM NAME: lin1, Memory: 256, CPUS: 1
message received VM NAME: lin2, Memory: 200, CPUS: 1
message received VM NAME: lin3, Memory: 222, CPUS: 1
connection closed
```

Service source:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import time
import logging
import virtualbox
from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection("ws://192.168.56.1:8888/ws")

class VMInventory(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "VMInventory"
    _svc_display_name_ = "VMInventory service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.stop_event = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        self.stop_requested = False

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.stop_event)
        self.stop_requested = True

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(
            servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
            servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
            (self._svc_name_,'')
        )
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        # Simulate a main loop
        vb = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
        while True:
            vms = vb.machines
            if self.stop_requested:
                break
            for vm in vms:
                ws.send("VM NAME: %s, Memory: %s, CPUS: %s" % (vm.name, str(vm.memory_size), str(vm.cpu_count)))
            time.sleep(5)
        ws.close()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(HelloWorldSvc)
```

Comment: All the `-debug` option does is attach stdout/stderr to the terminal, so it could be that your service code attempts to send output to one of them, but since they don't exist in non-debug mode that attempt causes a fatal error only when run in that mode.

Comment: Well, my service has no stdout, it only creates a websocket connection and sends some data to a remote server. I edited the code to write that data into a file and same as before, the file only gets written if I run the service in debug mode.

Comment: Something could be being written to stderr...for example from an un-handled exception. Perhaps you need to beef-up your service's error handling with some expansive `try/except` clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service itself is working just fine, my installation method was wrong. The correct way to install it is

```
python aservice.py  --username <username> --password <PASSWORD> --startup auto install
```

where `<username>` is prefixed with `.\` if using a local account, or with `DOMAIN\` if using a domain account.

For example

```
python aservice.py  --username .\johndoe --password mYstr0ngp4$$ --startup auto install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just run the commands from and elevated prompt, so right click and "Run-As_Administrator".  Unless you have to run under a specific user.