# Python Windows Service (pywin32) works in debug mode but fails as an installed Windows Service

Tags: python, service, windows-services, python-asyncio, pywin32

I made a websocket echo server and wanted to test it as a running service in the background.
The code for the Windows Service in Python was took from [here](https://thepythoncorner.com/posts/2018-08-01-how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/) and it uses `pywin32`.

**The code works well in debug mode** `python server.py debug` (meaning client receives message echoed back from server).

When I install it (only admin mode works) with `python server.py install` it appears in the Windows Services List, but when I try to start it and error message appear with: "*Windows could not start Python Echo WebSocket Server in local Computer. For more info...... error code 536870913.*"

- Python version: 3.10.4
- Windows 11

**Base class for Windows Service (SMWinservice.py):**

```
import socket

import win32serviceutil

import servicemanager
import win32event
import win32service


class SMWinservice(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    '''Base class to create winservice in Python'''

    _svc_name_ = 'pythonService'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'Python Service'
    _svc_description_ = 'Python Service Description'

    @classmethod
    def parse_command_line(cls):
        '''
        ClassMethod to parse the command line
        '''
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(cls)

    def __init__(self, args):
        '''
        Constructor of the winservice
        '''
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        '''
        Called when the service is asked to stop
        '''
        self.stop()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        '''
        Called when the service is asked to start
        '''
        self.start()
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))
        self.main()

    def start(self):
        '''
        Override to add logic before the start
        eg. running condition
        '''
        pass

    def stop(self):
        '''
        Override to add logic before the stop
        eg. invalidating running condition
        '''
        pass

    def main(self):
        '''
        Main class to be ovverridden to add logic
        '''
        pass

# entry point of the module: copy and paste into the new module
# ensuring you are calling the "parse_command_line" of the new created class
if __name__ == '__main__':
    SMWinservice.parse_command_line()
```

**Server implementation (server.py):**

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from SMWinservice import SMWinservice


DOMAIN = 'localhost'
PORT = XXX # Replace XXX with integer 


class EchoServerService(SMWinservice):
    _svc_name_ = "EchoWSService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Python Echo WebSocket Server"
    _svc_description_ = "A python written service of a WebSocket Echo Server running in localhost:XXX"

    def start(self):
        self.isrunning = True

    def stop(self):
        self.isrunning = False

    def process_message(self, message):
        print(message)
        return message

    async def handle(self, ws_client):
        async for message in ws_client:
            result = self.process_message(message)
            await ws_client.send(result)

    async def async_main(self):
        async with websockets.serve(self.handle, DOMAIN, PORT) as _:
            await asyncio.Future()

    def main(self):
        if self.isrunning:
            asyncio.run(self.async_main())
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    EchoServerService.parse_command_line()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows service written in Python works only in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580533/windows-service-written-in-python-works-only-in-debug-mode)

Comment: Tried that, but it only changed the error to "could not log in". I suspect the error is not caused by running the service at computer level insted of user level.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue and my solution is to run the websocket on another thread
e.g
threading.Thread(target=self.async_main).start()